# installing grunt locally as under privileged user

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I'm using node/grunt for deploying to a shared hosting server.
I have node installed in $HOME/opt/node

I don't know where `npm install -g grunt` is going to install it to, or how to tell npm to install global files to `$HOME/some/path`.

I ran `npm install grunt -g` and it seemed to work, but I cannot find the `grunt` binary anywhere.

Comment: Why do you want the binary? What is the issue you're having?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `grunt` command in your server's shell, you'll need to install the Grunt CLI.

```
npm install grunt-cli -g
```

Global modules are located here:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Comment: this is incorrect since I'm installing node locally in `$HOME/opt/node`